# Relationships returning wrong/null data (Laravel 5.2)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, relationships

Got a `domain table` which has a `One To Many relationship` with `domain_hosts_table`, `server_hosts_table` and `systems_table`. So far so good.

Calling the table data:

```
$domains = Domain::with('domain_host', 'server_host', 'system')->get();
```

*Domain* model :

```
public function domain_host()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\DomainHost', 'id');
}

public function server_host()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\ServerHost', 'id');
}

public function system()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\System', 'id');
}
```

*DomainHost*, *ServerHost*, *System* model :

```
public function domains()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Domain');
}
```

*Domains* table :

[image]

So far so good.

Let's take a look at what this particular table returns while being `foreached`.

[image]

The first 2 rows should be the same (basing on their IDs), and all rows after the first 2 are just empty.

(`dd` of the fetched data, notice the relations being empty at 4th object, 1st object actually has data).

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to define another parameter when defining my relationships:

```
public function domain_host()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\DomainHost', 'id', 'domain_host_id');
}

public function server_host()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\ServerHost', 'id', 'server_host_id');
}

public function system()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\System', 'id', 'system_id');
}
```

It was looking for the ID of the current row in the other table.